# Creating new column(s) from specific elements in ONE existing column in R

Tags: r, transpose

I currently have a dataset and one column that has specific (unordered) values that I need in order to plot it. Each variable is an integer that represents a specific category e.g 1 = VC, 2 = C, 3 = M etc. The values go from (1,2,3,4,5,8,9).

I currently have something like this:

```
    # A tibble: 571 x 1
    id
    <int>
     1     2
     2     3
     3     3
     4     1
   # ... with 561 more rows
```

However I'm trying to get something like this:

```
    # A tibble: n x 6
    id
    <int>  
    1 1 2 3 4 5 8 9 <- With these being the new columns 
    2 1 2 3 4 5 8 9
    3 1 2 3 4 5 8 9
    4 1 2 3 4 5 8 9
    #... etc
```

Basically I would like to go from a n x 1 to an ordered n x 6 so I can sum each occurrence of a 1,2,3 etc. I tried using transpose but I can't order it among other problems.

Please Help!

Comment: This sort of operation is a lot easier in matrices: `matrix(as.matrix(df), ncol = 6)`. You may need the `byrow` parameter or `t()`; it's hard to see with the current data.

Comment: Mathematically yes, how would you order each new column though? Also Inherently the number of rows will be uneven for each new column as well.

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood how you want to reshape. Assuming you're going to count occurrences of each number, the simplest way is `table`, e.g. `table(rpois(100, 5))`, or `dplyr::count` if you prefer.

Comment: Thats more along the line. I'm trying to plot it the one variable x = (id), however that limits me to one variable graphs. If my x = 1,2,3 I'm trying to make x_1 = 1, x_2 = 2, x_3 = 3 etc from that one initial x.

Comment: I suspect the answer is not very difficult, but I'm really struggling to understand what you're asking. From your example it looks like you just want to add the numbers 1 through 9 into extra columns because you have 9 variables. But in columns you talk about ordering each of the new columns. Are you able to flesh out and clear up the example?

Comment: My apologies, I have the one variable `id` that who's length is 1 to 561 it contains any possible amount of the integers `(1,2,3,4,5,8,9)`. It is unordered as well, I would like to create 7 columns each corresponding to a number in that list. So, ones go with 1, twos with 2 etc all the way to 9. I suppose order doesn't matter as long as I can create the new columns from their respective values in `id`.

Comment: Maybe you could reduce your example data a bit and show the actual result you would want from that, because it's still difficult to determine exactly what you want

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this?

```
# create a dataframe
d <- data.frame(A = c(1,1,2,1,1), B = c(2,2,10,1,2))

> d
  A  B
1 1  2
2 1  2
3 2 10
4 1  1
5 1  2


# we group the data by the columns A and B, and constructs a temporary extra 
# column, X which is the number of items in each group. Finally we use spread 
# to transform the data into the wanted format.

> d %>% dplyr::group_by(A,B) %>% 
    dplyr::summarise(X = n()) %>% 
    tidyr::spread(B,X, fill = 0)

# which return the data shown below, 

# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   A [2]
  A   `1`   `2`  `10`
* <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     3     0
2     2     0     0     1
```